# JSON (nested) object into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've been trying to to flatten a nested JSON object into a pandas dataframe. I've tried a number of methods but still can't seem to find a solution that works.

Json is linked here: https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/

Pandas.read_json output looks like this:

> 1    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Will Mark Cuban run for ...
>
> 2    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Will Andrew Cuomo run fo...
>
> 3    {'id': 2901, 'name': 'Will a woman be elected ...
>
> 4    {'id': 2902, 'name': 'Will the 2020 Democratic...

I want it to have ID, Name, etc. as columns in a pandas dataframe.

I understand that this is a fairly elementary question but I've hit a block and would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

ADDENDUM:

Here are the code bits that I am using:

This works fine:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/')
```

Then, I've tried the following:

```
df_data = pandas.json_normalize(r.data)
#I've tried about a dozen different variations playing the variables passed but always get the same result or the same result transposed into a very large column and 1 row.

df_data = pandas.read_json(r.data)
#again, same is true for trying a ton of variable combinations

df_data = pandas.read_json(r.data)
df_dat = df_data.drop('markets') #and
df_dat = df_data.drop([markets])
```

I am now considering importing the json object using the json library then dumping into a CSV and, if the issue persists then manually removing the first Column and Row and THEN reimporting it.

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Comment: Can you share the methods you've tried? Also, it's best to keep your question self-contained, so please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Done. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: Seriously? Well, that's embaressing.

Comment: In my browser it's XML, yet when I get the page using requests, the result is JSON.

Comment: Update: I got it to send XML by setting the `"Accept"` header to `"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"`.

Comment: Update 2: You can use `"Accept": "application/json"` or `"Accept": "application/xml"`, whose effect is self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get `markets` value of dict
like this (And there is no need to use `read_json`):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 5)
pd.set_option('display.width', 260)
pd.set_option('mode.use_inf_as_na', True)


proxy = {"http": "http://127.0.0.1:1080", "https": "https://127.0.0.1:1080"}

r = requests.get('https://www.predictit.org/api/marketdata/all/', proxies=proxy, verify=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['markets'])

print(df.head())

     id                                               name  ...                    timeStamp status
0  2721  Which party will win the 2020 U.S. presidentia...  ...  2020-03-18T22:23:43.4549039   Open
1  2747         Will Mark Cuban run for president in 2020?  ...  2020-03-18T22:23:43.4549039   Open
2  2875       Will Andrew Cuomo run for president in 2020?  ...  2020-03-18T22:23:43.4549039   Open
3  2901    Will a woman be elected U.S. president in 2020?  ...  2020-03-18T22:23:43.4549039   Open
4  2902  Will the 2020 Democratic nominee for president...  ...  2020-03-18T22:23:43.4549039   Open

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

And the columns `contracts` is nested, you can use df `apply` to open it.

Comment: Thanks. This is great. I am trying it now. Why do I need the proxy setting?

Comment: @ooitzoo You don't need that. That's what I need. im in China

Comment: Got any idea how to break out the nested json objects? You mentioned df.apply but I am not seeing how to do to that.

Comment: @ooitzoo _Got any idea how to break out the nested json objects?_ Be careful, there really isn't such a thing as a "JSON object" here, those are just plain old Python dicts.

Comment: @ooitzoo See this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply   ```eg: df['key'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['key'])```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm just being dense or what but I can't see how to use the apply function to this situation. I'm getting there with .from_dict(['random frame']) but not totally there.